# create a new table that how to pull the data from different table using one key column using dax function

Tags: powerbi-desktop

i have two table A and B

```
Table 1
| key 1    |  marks
| -------  | --------
|  a       |  1
|  a       |  11
|  b       |  2
|  b       |  22
|  c       |  3
|  c       |  33


Table 2
| key 2    | book     |
| -------- | -------- |
| a        | aa       |
| a        | aaa      |
| b        | bb       |
| b        | bbb      |
| c        | cc       |
| c        | ccc      |
```

Result table using dax:

[image]

I want new output table like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this by creating a new table command:

Note: Join columns must have the same name before below code is applied; so change the name of the 2nd table column from key 2 to key 1.

```
Result_Table = 
VAR Table2_00 =
    TREATAS ( 'Table 1', 'Table 2'[key 1], 'Table 1'[marks])
VAR Result =
    NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN ( Table2_00, 'Table 2' )
RETURN
    Result
```

If we check the result, It gives us:

[image: Check_Result]